Should vosotros or ustedes be used in a book that has a primarily South American audience?
Should vosotros or ustedes be used in a book that has a primarily South American audience? I wrote in vosotros form, because I thought that was better for a universal Spanish-speaking audience, especially for a book (which uses written register, not spoken register). However, Hispanic readers seem to dislike coming across the vosotros form in my book.
Aren't Hispanic Spanish speakers sufficiently exposed to vosotros to comprehend it, even if they don't use it themselves?
If my intended audience is primarily South/Central American, should I use only the Ustedes form? (Does that also work for users of the Vos form?)

Just to clarify, any Spanish speaker would be considered Hispanic, whether they are from Spain or Latin America. People from Latin America (including those who speak other languages like Portuguese) are considered Latino or Latina, and those who speak Spanish are considered Hispanic no matter their country of origin. So a Hispanic Spanish speaker isn't really any different from any other Spanish speaker.

Todo depende del lugar. En América, ‘vosotros’ tiene un toque arcaizante por lo que podría ir mejor en traducciones de textos clásicos o poéticos para ir con ese tono literario. Después, para habler normal se dice ‘ustedes’. En cuanto a lo de ‘vos’, de nuevo depende del lugar. En general deberías usar ‘tú’, pero en el español rioplatense suena demasiado distante; de ahí que se prefiera ‘vos’. Conclusión: Todo depende del lugar, todo depende del lugar. Lo que queda bien en un lado puede sonar mal en el otro, o viceversa.

Just a side note.  There is a Bible translation, Reina Valera, that is widely used among Protestants in South America.  It uses vosotros.  It's well understood, but it gives the sense that the text is very old.  Sort of like using "thee" and "thou" in an English Bible.

For a primarily Latin American audience, you should probably use the "ustedes" form since that's what they usually use. Generally, people from Central/South American countries will understand "vosotros" and know how to use it but it will not sound as natural to them and will sound a little foreign.
Since only a couple of countries (Argentina, Paraguay, and Uruguay, for example) use the "vos" form, you should not use it, since Spanish speakers from those countries will understand "ustedes" and that is the most widely used form.
Spanish speakers from Spain will probably find "ustedes" to seem a little bit too formal, but if you're writing for Latin American audiences then you should cater to their way of speaking instead of the way Spain does things.
Sources:
https://springlanguages.com/learn-spanish/ustedes-vs-vosotros/
https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/vos

Thanks for the response!

They don't really "know how to use it" because many don't know the conjugation ending for vosotors. However, they will understand it.
